# SELECT CASE doesn't proceed to next condition

Tags: mysql, select, case

I have a table with orders and my task is to output orders with status "complete" as well as all of orders grouped by that status:

```
select (case 
when o.status = "complete" then 'Complete orders'
when o.status = "complete" or o.status != "complete" then 'All orders' 
end)
```

It seems like the second condition is being replaced by ELSE, because what I see in the output is
Complete orders and Incomplete orders.

I can understand "why", my question is more like "how to".

I have a solution that works well in production: first I select all orders and the second select is complete orders and I `union all` those guys. Mentioned select statement is huge and I duplicate it with only extra `where o.status = 'complete'` which is frustrating.

Comment: Your case expression does not make any sense, some sample data would help.

Answer (score 0):

Stu is correct. The logic of your select statement is confusing. First you check if status is complete and then
you check if the status is complete OR not complete.

And I'm not sure how you're getting 'Complete orders and Incomplete orders' as a result, as the string 'Incomplete orders' is nowhere in your code.

Something like this might point you in the right direction.

SELECT
customer,
order_status,

CASE order_status

WHEN 'complete' THEN 'Complete Orders'

ELSE 'Incomplete orders'

END

FROM orders_table;